# Moving from Zend Framework 1.5 to 1.11

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-db

I have my application that was programmed about 3 years ago using Zend Framework 1.5 running on PHP 5.3 [Earlier version? 5.3 introduced `goto` as a keyword].

I had to move my application to a new web host that is running on a newer version of PHP that has the `goto` keyword. I now get errors with a `goto()` function implemented in ZF 1.5. So I decided to move my application on ZF 1.11 hoping that the latest version would get me off such errors. However, by doing so, I have only run into major errors in my application's Zend way of communicating with my database. And another few errors such as

> Call to a member function setMessage() on a non-object

on a line that has

```
$form->caller_id->getValidator('Zend_Validate_NotEmpty')->setMessage('Please select your name from the caller list!', 'isEmpty');
```

I am not well familiar with Zend. I have worked with CakePHP and understand the MVC architecture.

Can someone suggest how I should approach this problem? I feel kind of lost!

Comment: The current version of PHP is 5.4.5 so I would be surprised if you found a host running 5.5. ZF does not use goto in any way, and goto was added in PHP 5.3 which you say your application was written for. Please could you show a little more of the code that is causing the error, and let us know what PHP version your new host is actually running.

Comment: See [this old bug](http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-3022) about `goto` in ZF 1.5.1. I suspect you've moved from PHP < 5.3 to PHP 5.3. I doubt many hosting providers are running 5.4 already given that there are still those that haven't upgraded to 5.3 yet.

Comment: Nice spot. Wouldn't his updating to ZF 1.11 have fixed this though?

Comment: @TimFountain You are right, its php 5.4.5 and not 5.5 (my bad).

Comment: My application is in Zend 1.5.1 and worked well with php5.2.6 ..This web host is a University machine and I don't have much choice on it.

Comment: ZF will work fine on 5.4.5, we just need to find out what the issue is. Please could you edit your question to include the last few lines before the `getValidator()` call which is failing? We need to see what that is being called on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to change the string name of the validator (I tried this on my own form and the short name 'NotEmpty' returns the object and 'Zend_Validate_NotEmpty' returns false):

current:

```
$form->caller_id->getValidator('Zend_Validate_NotEmpty')->setMessage('Please select your name from the caller list!', 'isEmpty');
```

new:

```
$form->caller_id->getValidator('NotEmpty')->setMessage('Please select your name from the caller list!', 'isEmpty');
```